# How to catch two exceptions of the same type and handle them differently?

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

I have a method which makes calls to two external methods. Both these methods may throw an "IllegalInputException" but these exceptions are handled differently depending on which method threw them.

Currently I have them placed under two try-catch blocks:

```
void someMethod() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (IllegalInputException e1) {
        handleError("doSomething");
    }
    try {
        doSomethingElse();
    } catch (IllegalInputException e2) {
        handleError("doSomethingElse");
    }
}
```

Is there some way to check which of the two method calls is the one that threw the exception?
Or more generally - other than defining two separate Exception classes, is there a more elegant/correct way to handle such a situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems correct and neat

Comment: seems correct, but you can also split someMethod() into two, look for my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to check which of the two method calls is the one that threw the exception?

You can do this literally by getting the stack trace and iterating through it to find the method you called.  I don't recommend you do this as it's more complicated and easily broken.

Another approach is to set a flag you can use.

```
void someMethod() {
    String method = "none";
    try {
        method = "doSomething";
        doSomething();

        method = "doSomethingElse";
        doSomethingElse();
    } catch (IllegalInputException e) {
        handleError(method, e); // don't ignore the exception.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it terribly elegant, but here's an option.

```
void someMethod() {
    doSafely(() -> doSomething(), "doSomething");
    doSafely(() -> doSomethingElse(), "doSomethingElse");
}
private void doSafely(Runnable r, String argument) {
    try {
        r.run();
    } catch (IllegalInputException e) {
        handleError(argument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void someMethod() {
  //this is template method pattern
  callDoSomething();
  callDoSomethingelse(); 
}

void callDoSomething() {
  try {
     doSomething();
  } catch (IllegalInputException e1) {
     handleError("doSomething");
  }
}

void callDoSomethingelse() {
  try {
     doSomethingElse();
  } catch (IllegalInputException e2) {
     handleError("doSomethingElse");
  }
}
```